# Finding image dataset of color-blindness charts

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, images, classification

I had an idea to train a CNN to classify numbers seen on color-blindness charts like the one seen below.

[image]

I have Google for such dataset but did not find anything. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a benchmark using the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).  There are [many tutorials and articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=training+cnn+mnist) written on training a CNN for digit recognition.  You might also want to consider preprocessing your color-blindness charts input data (e.g. converting to grayscale, enhancing digit contrast).